Files are not updated after the Jenkins Build success triggered by the GitHub Actions as expected
After removing the following command git reset --hard origin/${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} || { echo "git reset failed"; exit 1; } from the trigger-jenkins-build.yml file, now the files old_build_number.txt and new_build_number.txt files are updated.
After updated the both text files, the changes are push back to the repository and that triggers Jenkins again these text files are updated and push that triggers Jenkins, it running continuously as a loop. How to update these text files after Jenkins build completed without pushing these changes to repository.
Note: This is the continuation to debug the issue of the Files are not updated after the Jenkins Build success triggered by the GitHub Actions
The trigger-jenkins-build.yml code is here

If you want the workflow to ignore updates to some paths you can add them to the trigger definition:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
    paths-ignore:
      - ".github/build_numbers/old_build_number.txt"
      - ".github/build_numbers/new_build_number.txt"

See path-ignore documentation here.

Yes it is working, but the new_build_number.txt file is updated as empty and old_build_number.txt file is updated as expected. Here is the
workflow yaml file and build_number folder  .Please post if you have any suggestions on this yaml file to update for my expected output

There is only so much I can do for points. We have reached this limit. Taking it farther doesn't benefit the StackOverflow community, as your issues are very specific to your workflow and to your project. We can definitely do more on a paid consultancy basis.

Ok Thanks I will check my workflow
